# Capture a gif with android custom camera

Tags: java, android, android-camera, gif

Is it possible to capture a gif with custom camera? I thought about animating pictures or converting video file into a gif file.

Comment: I'm sorry it's probably a misunderstanding but my question actually was: how to create a custom camera that records gifs. Thanks

Comment: They will close that, because here is forbidden to ask for software. Which is sometimes reasonable (nobody wants debates like "but my library is better!" "no, my is better!"), but not always, despite that it is always forced. They will probably delete your question. In this case, I suggest a little bit of constructivity: first, ask not for the name of the API, but for the _usage_ of the android API. Second: ask this of softwarecs.stackexchange.com , which is exactly for such questions. Next to that, you could ask this on android.stackexchange.com as well, they are also friendlier.

Comment: I'm not asking for software, but just some tips and tricks to get started.

Comment: If you can't program even android, then you should ask for good android tutorials. And if you are [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/), I hope you will burn in the hell until the eternity.

Comment: I take it "capture a gif" means "capture several frames from the camera and convert them into an animated gif"?  There is no "record to gif" mode in the API.

Comment: should I convert videos into gifs?